# how do I setup vimeo api with angular2

Tags: angular, vimeo-api

I'm trying to use the https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js with my angular2 project.
Here is what I've done.

1. ran 'npm install vimeo'
2. created 'vimeo.service.ts'
3. tried to `import {Vimeo} from '../../node_modules/vimeo';`

At the import line I get an error saying

> ' [ts] Module '../../node_modules/vimeo' was resolved to
>   '/Users/../GitHub/Angular2-GettingStarted/APM -
>   Final/node_modules/vimeo/index.js', but '--allowJs' is not set'

What am I doing wrong? Is there a working Angular2 example using this api that I could work off of?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's not an es6 library, so try doing a require instead.

```
const Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;

// then when initializing it 
const lib   = new Vimeo(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like something along those lines would do the trick!